# Laravel SQL query on condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

suppose i have a function like bellow (in Laravel 4.2):

```
public static function getResult($class_id,$section_id,$session,$term,$setTerm = ture)
{
     $result = self::with('Student','Student.getClass','Student.getSection')
        ->where('class_id',$class_id)
        ->where('section_id',$section_id)
        ->where('exam_year',$session)
        ->where('term',$term)
        ->orderBy('class_roll','ASC')->get();

    return $result;

}
```

so if `$setTerm` is set to false then `(->where('term',$term))` should not be executed.

How to do that conditional things in Laravel during query building ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it, this should work:

```
public static function getResult($class_id,$section_id,$session,$term,$setTerm = ture)
{
     $result = self::with('Student','Student.getClass','Student.getSection')
        ->where('class_id',$class_id)
        ->where('section_id',$section_id)
        ->where('exam_year',$session);

     if($setTerm){ 
        $result->where('term',$term);
     }

     $result->orderBy('class_roll','ASC')->get();

     return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the function to be this:

```
public static function getResult($class_id,$section_id,$session,$term,$setTerm = true)
{
     $query = self::with('Student','Student.getClass','Student.getSection')
        ->where('class_id',$class_id)
        ->where('section_id',$section_id)
        ->where('exam_year',$session);

    if ($setTerm) {
        $query->where('term',$term);
    }

    return $query->orderBy('class_roll','ASC')->get();    
}
```

Comment: One little flaw, you have to assign the return value of `get()` to `$query` or return it directly. Otherwise `getResult()` will return a query builder instance and not the actual result.